# Advice and guidance for a rough program

Tags: graph, uber-api, floyd-warshall

I'm new to data structures and I have to build a rough version of Uber using graph, Floyd Warshall algorithm and search tree I think. Are there any similar problems and can I get some guidance on how to tackle this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would check out google maps api.
Its a fast easy way to get started on the mapping side.

Here's a link to get started

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial